# Sigma Algebra on infinite coin tossing experiment until head appears

Tags: measure-theory

Consider an experiment in which a coin is tossed until a head appears. So, set of outcomes will contain elements like H, TH, TTH, etc. How can we construct a sigma algebra so that probabilities can be assigned to singleton elements of outcome set? Will it be countable?

Comment: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/108106083/lecture8_Infinite%20Coin%20Toss.pdf